# String to list of dictionaries using .split()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, split, list-comprehension

I would like split data given from telnet query. I got two case:

#### Single data:

```
user_name=toto user_password=12345 user_type=admin`
```

#### Multiple data:

```
user_name=toto user_password=12345 user_type=admin|user_name=tata user_password=12345 user_type=user|user_name=tonton user_password=12345 user_type=moderator
```

I have tried to build my dictionary for single data with `data = dict(item.split("=") for item in data.split(' '))`, but I always get this error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

I don't find any good solution to build my dictionary with single feature. What I am expecting is:

```
{'user_name':'tata','user_password':'12345','user_type':'admin'} 

for multiple results: 
{{'user_name':'tata','user_password':'12345','user_type':'admin'} {'user_name':'toto','user_password':'12345','user_type':'user'}{'user_name':'tonton','user_password':'12345','user_type':'moderator'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted in your question works fine on both Python 2 and Python 3 for single data:

```
$ python3
>>> s = "user_name=toto user_password=12345 user_type=admin"
>>> dict(item.split("=") for item in s.split(' '))
{'user_password': '12345', 'user_name': 'toto', 'user_type': 'admin'}

$ python2
>>> dict(item.split("=") for item in s.split(' '))
{'user_password': '12345', 'user_name': 'toto', 'user_type': 'admin'}
```

For multiple data, you just need to put another level of list comprehension:

```
>>> s = "user_name=toto user_password=12345 user_type=admin|user_name=tata user_password=12345 user_type=user|user_name=tonton user_password=12345 user_type=moderator"
>>> [dict(item.split("=") for item in ss.split()) for ss in s.split('|')]
[{'user_password': '12345', 'user_name': 'toto', 'user_type': 'admin'}, 
 {'user_password': '12345', 'user_name': 'tata', 'user_type': 'user'},
 {'user_password': '12345', 'user_name': 'tonton', 'user_type': 'moderator'}]
```

The process here is:

1. Split the string at each pipe `|` and make a list of it
2. For each item of this list, split by space (default separator of `split()`)
3. Then for each sub-element of each list, split by equal `=` and use it as a key-value for the dictionary

Comment: Which version of Python (it can't work with Python <= 2.6 but it would give you a SyntaxError anyway)? The last snippet of code in my answer gives me good results. Is the error happening with the same string example or with a different one?

Comment: I think the problem come from telnetlib.read, when i put the results directly in string var this work :/